# Replace block of text inside a file using the contents of another file using sed

Tags: sed

I am looking to replace a block of text that is between markers with the contents of another file.
I came across this solution but it only works with one line

```
$ sed -n '/foo/{p;:a;N;/bar/!ba;s/.*\n/REPLACEMENT\n/};p' file
line 1
line 2
foo
REPLACEMENT
bar
line 6
line 7
```

I am trying to get the following working but it's not.

```
content=`cat file_content` 
sed -n '/foo/{p;:a;N;/bar/!ba;s/.*\n/${content}\n/};p' file
```

output

```
line 1
line 2
foo
${content}
bar
line 6
line 7
```

How can I get ${content} to list the output of the file?

Comment: sed -n '/foo/{p;:a;N;/bar/!ba;s/.*\n/'"${content}"'\n/};p' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Apart from  single quoted string  in shell prohibiting any expansion from taking place, `content` may include character that throw `sed` off... `/` would confuse it here. You may want to check `r` command out for reading and appending file content in `sed`.

Comment: sh-4.2$ echo "${content}"
test1
1
3
4
45
5
454
45454
4545
454
46
454
4
64
6
6
46


646
46

466
4
6464

646

46

64
46
646453

3
3
3
3
66
66

Comment: What if `foo` and/or `bar` occurred twice in the file? Should we replace the text from the first foo to the first bar, or first foo to last bar or last foo to first bar after it or something else? What if foo existed but bar did not? Should we replace from foo to the end of the file? What if `foo` existed as part of some other string like `myfoobad`? What if `foo` and `bar` existing on the same line like `foo REPLACEME bar`? What if foo or bar contained regexp metachars - should they be treated as literal chars or not? etc, etc... You have a lot to clarify about your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I guess this should be a reasonably short way of doing it to replace text between `foo` and `bar` lines with content of file `file_content`:

```
sed -e '/^foo$/,/^bar$/{/^bar$/{x;r content_file
D};d}' file
```

For range of lines matching `^foo$` and `^bar$`. If line matches `^bar$` swap (empty) hold space into pattern space, read and append content of `content_file`, then delete pattern space up to first newline and start next cycle with the reminder of the pattern space. For all other lines in that range... just drop the line (delete patter space and move to the next line of input).

Otherwise to the result of your question... any string enclosed in single quotes is taken literally by shell and without any expansion (also of variables) taking place. `'${content}'` means literally `${content}` and that is also part of the argument passed to `sed`, whereas double quote text (`"${content}"`) would still see shell expand variable to what its value before becoming part of the `sed` arguments. Since that could still see content tripping up `sed`, I would opt for the `r` method for being more generic / robust.

---

EDIT: Edit keeping the start and end lines in (since I've misread the question):

```
sed -e '/^foo$/,/^bar$/{/^foo$/{r content_file
p};/^bar$/!d}' file
```

This time for range between matched of `^foo$` and `^bar$`... for opening line matching `^foo$` we it `r`eads content from `content_file` appending it to pattern space and then `p`rints it (because of `d`elete that follow). Then for all line in the range not matching the closing line pattern `^bar$` it just drops it and moves on.

Comment: it works as expected; but can you modify the answer to keep foo and bar in the file.

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/foo/,/bar/{//!d;/foo/s//&\n'${content}'/}' file`

From foo to bar, delete lines not matching previous match `//!d`.

On foo line, replace match `&` with match followed by `\n${content}`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/foo/!b;:a;$b;N;/bar/!ba;P;s/.*\n//;e cat contentFile' file
```

Print all lines until one containing `foo`.

If this is the last line, then there will never be a line containing `bar` so break out and do not insert the `contentFile`.

Otherwise, append the next line and check for it containing `bar`, if not repeat.

The pattern space should now contain both `foo` and `bar` so, print the first line (containing `foo`), remove all other lines other than the one containing `bar`, print the file `contentFile` and then print the last line of the collection containing `bar`.

N.B. This does not insert the `contentFile` unless both `foo` and `bar` exist in `file`. Also the `e` command will evaluate the `cat contentFile` immediately and insert the result into the output stream before printing the line containing `bar`, whereas the `r` command always prints to the output stream after the implicit print of the sed cycle.
An alternative:

```
sed -ne '/foo/{p;:a;n;/bar/!ba;e cat contentFile' -e '};p' file
```

However this solution will only print lines before `foo` if `file` does not have a line containing `bar`.