# Find and replace part of the text of one file with the contents of another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with the following contents

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF1' > scriptfile1.sh
file1 command1
file1 command2
file1 command3
EOF1
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF2' > scriptfile2.sh
file2 command1
file2 command2
file2 command3
EOF2
.... some commands
```

and I have the following files

```
file1.sh
new command1 for file1
new command2 for file1
new command3 for file1

file2.sh
new command1 for file2
new command2 for file2
new command3 for file2
```

I want from file script.sh to find the part of text that starts with "cat << 'EOF1' > file1.sh"
and ends with "EOF1" and then replaced with the content of file1.sh and so on ....

And after that my output of script.sh to be like that

```
#!/bin/bash
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF1' > scriptfile1.sh
new command1 for file1
new command2 for file1
new command3 for file1
EOF1
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF2' > scriptfile2.sh
new command1 for file2
new command2 for file2
new command3 for file2
EOF2
.... some commands
```

I have found the following but I can't make it work

[Replace block of text inside a file using the contents of another file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982438/replace-block-of-text-inside-a-file-using-the-contents-of-another-file-using-sed)

How can I do it preferably with the awk

Comment: What did you try with awk, with what result and what was wrong with it?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/a/806942/652023) answer your question?

Comment: I could tell you the solution from within Vim easy enough, but I fear that wouldn't be the kind of solution you're thinking of as Vim solutions look a bit like obfuscated code contests. ;-) [Related question on vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/how-to-replace-content-between-two-patterns-from-the-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case where you can generate the names of the files to be read as you go, I'd do the following (using any awk in any shell on every Unix box):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 == hereEnd {
    hereEnd = ""
}
hereEnd == "" {
    print
    if ( /^cat <</ ) {
        gsub(/["\047]/," ")
        hereEnd = $3
        file = "file" (++hereCnt) ".sh"
        while ( (getline line < file) > 0 ) {
            print line
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk script.sh
#!/bin/bash
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF1' > scriptfile1.sh
new command1 for file1
new command2 for file1
new command3 for file1
EOF1
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF2' > scriptfile2.sh
new command1 for file2
new command2 for file2
new command3 for file2
EOF2
.... some commands
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for caveats of using `getline`.

Alternatively you could read each of the intermediate files specified on the command line into memory, e.g. with GNU awk for `ARGIND`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
ARGIND < (ARGC-1) {
    file[ARGIND] = (FNR>1 ? file[ARGIND] ORS : "") $0
    next
}
$0 == hereEnd {
    hereEnd = ""
}
hereEnd == "" {
    print
    if ( /^cat <</ ) {
        gsub(/["\047]/," ")
        hereEnd = $3
        print file[++hereCnt]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file{1..2}.sh script.sh
#!/bin/bash
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF1' > scriptfile1.sh
new command1 for file1
new command2 for file1
new command3 for file1
EOF1
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF2' > scriptfile2.sh
new command1 for file2
new command2 for file2
new command3 for file2
EOF2
.... some commands
```

If you don't have GNU awk you can do the same by just adding `FNR==1 { ARGIND++ }` at the start of the script.

The above assumes you have at least as many `fileN.sh` files as you have here documents in `script.sh`. With the above you don't need to have separate `EOF1`, `EOF2`, delimiters for each here doc, they could all just use `EOF` or any other symbol.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
cat subs.sed

/^cat << 'EOF1'.*/,/^EOF1$/ {
//!d
/^cat /r file1.sh
}
/^cat << 'EOF2'.*/,/^EOF2$/ {
//!d
/^cat /r file2.sh
}

# use it as:

sed -f subs.sed script.sh

#!/bin/bash
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF1' > scriptfile1.sh
new command1 for file1
new command2 for file1
new command3 for file1
EOF1
.... some commands
cat << 'EOF2' > scriptfile2.sh
new command1 for file2
new command2 for file2
new command3 for file2
EOF2
.... some commands
```

Comment: I test it but it gives me the error "extra characters after command" at line with "//!d" command.
And because I do not understand how the sed command works I would prefer if you can write something with the awk command that I understand better.

Comment: That worked for me on BSD as well gnu-sed. What is your sed version?

Comment: My sed version is (GNU sed) 4.4 on a GNU bash, version 4.1.0(2)-release (mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: I have GNU sed 4.8 and this code worked fine.